# Change the language using resource files without changing the culture MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have implemented the culture changing to my application and it works fine, but I face problem with date and the date picker tool. So, how do I implement just the resource file without changing the culture **OR** let the culture fixed and use the resource file to change the model item.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No sure if it is ASP terminology but what is culture, could you give an example of a resource file or code / print screen of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: What Datepicker tool are you using ? Bootstrap or Kendo or anyother?